# Convexity of a minimum function

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, convexity, convex-analysis, mapping-class-groups

I was reading a proof of $9g-9$ theorem which states that $9g-9$ length parameters are sufficient the parametrize the Teichmuller space of a closed surface of genus $g$. The proof uses the following fact.

---

> **Theorem:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly conves function. If the function $F:\mathbb{R^m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$F(x) = \min \left\{ f(x,y) ; y \in \mathbb{R}^n \right\}$$ is well defined, i.e., if the minimum always exists then $F$ is always strictly convex.

---

Can someone please give me any proof or at least idea of the proof of this fact.

P.S: I am reading the book "A primer on mapping class group." And I don't want a reference.

Comment: I gave a reference because that book is freedly downloadable from the link provided. It's strange to explicitly forbid a reference though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a standard result in convex analysis. See for example, $\S$3.2.5 of [*Convex Optimization*](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) by Boyd and Vandenberghe (just slightly modify their proof to conclude strictness).

Comment: Thank you very much. What I mean above is references which are not papers.

Answer (score 4):

An idea of the proof. For the convexity of $F$: a function is convex iff its epigraph is convex; the epigraph of $F$ is the projection of the epigraph of $f$; the projection of a convex set is convex. Note that this part also work with $\inf$ more generally that $\min$ in the definition.

For the strict convexity: assume that $F$ is convex but not strictly convex. Then, up to adding  a linear form to $F$, the  $F$ has more than a minimum point. Any minimum point of $F$ is the projection of a minimum point of $f$, and since $F$ has more than a minimum point, so does $f$, and $f$ is not strictly convex.

Finally, note that a strictly convex and bounded below function $f$ does not produce in general a strictly convex $F(x):=\inf_y f(x,y)$, like the example of $f(x,y):=\exp(x^2/2+y)$ shows, for $f$ is strictly convex and $F$ is identically $0$.